# mysql create table based on columns from another table and auto updated

Tags: mysql

I could have the wording 'wrong' here (new to mysql) but i hope i've explained what I'm trying to do well.

i have a table called submissions with 4 fields submitId, studentName, submitDate, status

> - status refers to whether they got admitted or not.
> - submitId is auto incremented

Now i wanted to create another table based on that, but only if the status is true, this new table would have the submitId, studentName, submitDate, plus additional fields.

> - this table would have a new auto increment studentId

how would i do that so it automatically updates any new entry to the first table on the second table, but not overwrite the additional content of table 2.

i thought of using a view, but u can't add new columns on the view, right?
do i have the logic wrong here or what are the options, could someone please point me in the right direction, thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement a **trigger** of some sort on the submissions table, but it's not clear what the specific conditions would be. i.e. on insert? on update? and for the second table, what the actions would be - insert? update?

Comment: it would be when the status changes, so on update.
Now im trying to add new columns for address, email and link then to table 2

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a trigger.   See:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html

You can create the trigger so that when a row is inserted into `submissions` with status=true, it inserts a row into your new student table.  It would look something like this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER sub_ins_check AFTER INSERT ON submissions
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
         IF NEW.status = 1 THEN
           INSERT INTO your_new_table (student_name, submit_date, submit_id) VALUES (NEW.student_name, NEW.submit_date, NEW.submit_id);
         END IF;
     END;//
delimiter ;
```

Then create another trigger so that when a row is updated in submissions, it updates the row with the same submit_id in your new table, like this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER sub_ins_check AFTER UPDATE ON submissions
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
         IF NEW.status = 1 THEN
           UPDATE your_new_table SET student_name = NEW.student_name, submit_date = NEW.submit_date, (etc..)) WHERE submit_id = NEW.submit_id;
         END IF;
     END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ireeder that was it, now taking it a step further, say on submissions  table i have a contacts and email column, could i then add that linked column to the new table, so in case of changes it all gets updated.
How would i do that?

Comment: @Ireeded it's not behaving as expected, it just keeps adding, how would i do a check if the submit_id already exists and only add if it does not exist?
Because this way im having duplicates

Comment: You could create a new trigger on INSERT to create the initial record in your new table, and modify the trigger on UPDATE in my example to UPDATE the row in your new table where NEW.submit_id = submit_id using any updated columns.  I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I think your data model is wrong. Remember that student my have several submissions and there may be number of students with the same name. You must distinguish them.
Is there any reason you want to duplicate student data in both tables?
If you're new to `SQL`, read about **table normalization** first.
In you `Student` table you should store students data and in `Submission` table - guess what :)

Comment: thanks @Wirus i welcome the comment, and table normalization is one of the things i have been trying to understand, my thinking was, submissions would be done online, so it would be easier to just put everything in one table (through php) and then once they have been accepted additional info would be added, the studentId would be for the actual student ID so i needed to auto increment and that also gives me a 'clean' table with only the relevant data to then process.
But if u  would elaborate i would appreciate, maybe your right and i could do it in a better way.
Thanks

Comment: Let me understand your case. Submissions are applications for field of studies, right? If someone accepts submission, then given person becomes students. Am I right?

Comment: yes you are right, i had a long hard think about it and you are right, the model is wrong (noob error...lol) because a student may submit for different courses for example, so im thinking to have a student table with the student details (with a password) to confirm who is who, a table with the courses and a table for who is accepted or not, does that make sense?
what i don't know yet is how i would link all of that together, if you can point me to an example i would appreciate.
side question: are table joins very taxing performance wise, as data gets added?

Comment: This is what I wanted to point out after you confirm my doubts - user may have several accepted submission and it's still one student. So, as you noted, it should be focused around student's account, which will be the starting point to submit for a course. So, you will have Student and Courses tables, now you need StudentCourses table, that will have studentId, courseId, submissionDate, status etc. This is how you join it.

Comment: Don't worry about joins performance and remember, that mysql is relational database - it's designed for relations :). For table's primary key rdbms automatically creates index, you may additionally create indexes on StudentCourses.studentId and StudentCourses.courseId fields.

Comment: This is classic example of many to many relationship. Type it in google it will give you examples how to structure tables, create queries to join all those together etc. And you may of course ask further questions (after reading ;) ) :)

Comment: lol @Wirus i have been looking into, one quick question, in terms of foreign keys is it a bad idea to use varchar im just thinking that for things like courses it would be alot easier and less error prone to use varchar as opposed to int.
Thanks

Comment: Well, you may find many discussions regarding this topic, you may google them. One is for sure. If you use varchar, something that is meaningful to your model, you may want to change this value some day. If you just use auto incremented value, you're free to change course codes etc. I'd suggest using sequential numeric primary keys.

Comment: i thought i could also makes those changes or keep adding with a varchar, (for courses and stuff like that) it would just make it easier should one have to make manual edits at any stage.

Comment: I'm not sure I got the point, but you may always create sequential numeric primary key and have unique varchar code for courses etc. But you'll have to think out what will be the best for you. Reading and practicing on real problems will make you master ;)

Comment: thanks, that's the plan :)
It's saying here to move to a chat, but then i don't have enough points for a chat, so if u do, hit me up and maybe u can help me clarify a few things, if u have a moment.
In the meantime i have been doing some work on it, i will open a new post with the link to the fiddle, that way it should be easier to see what im trying to do.
Thanks for your help

Comment: i placed a new post with more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198930/mysql-help-and-guidance-with-db-normalising-relationships-and-foreign-keys) and a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2) to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hi Bob, I'm having hot time (is there such saying in English? to say about being very busy?) And in a few days I'm gonna start long awaiting leave so I will not be able to help you. I'm sure you'll get answers on this another post though :). I hope I've been helpful to you and deserved at least +1? ;) I know... I'm such a materialist... ;)

Comment: yes, u do deserve the +1 my bad for not doing it sooner (just getting used to forum intricacies).
You have been very helpful and will be missed but i hope u make the most of ur leave and have fun.
Nothing wrong with asking for what u are due :)

Comment: I'm gonna have visitors, so will have very limitted access to my PC, but mainly it will be, as we call it, 'typical Polish leave', this means I'll spend it on repairs etc :) But I hope I'll manage to go somewhere for few days :)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is step back and consider the problem from the perspective of logical entities.

You've identified two entities that I can see - student and submission. "Student" is an obvious entity which you may choose NOT to store in your database, but it may be better that you do. "Submission" is a more obvious one, but what is not so obvious is what a "submission" actually *is*. Let's assume it is some sort of transaction.

You've mentioned a "second table" without a clear indication of its role in the solution. The best I could infer is that it is meant to be some sort of historical trail on activity against a **submission**. If true, then I could envision a physical schema sketched out as follows:

**Student** table. One row per student; contains information about a student (name, id, etc.). Primary key would probably be an auto-incremented number.

**Submission** table. One row per submission; includes a foreign key to the **student** table (referencing the primary key); has its own primary key, also an auto-incremented integer. Also has triggers defined for INSERT and UPDATE. INSERT trigger causes INSERT into **submission_log** table; UPDATE trigger also causes INSERT into **submission_log** table.

**Submission_log** table. One row per event against the **submission** table. Includes all the fields of **submission** plus its own primary key (submission's primary key is a foreign key here), and includes an indicator field for whether it represents an insert or update on **submission**.

The purpose of the above is not to supply a solution, or even the framework of a solution, but rather to get you to think in terms of the logical entities you want to model in your solution, and their relationships to each other. When you have a clear picture of the logical model, it will be much easier to determine what tables are required, what their roles are, and how they will be used and how they will relate to each other.

Comment: What really piss me off on stackoverflow are people that can't figure out something by themselve and just read other answers and comments, modify it a bit, add something more or less important and create own answer basing on collected information, just 'points hunters'. Sorry man, but without my hours spent on helping and answering to Bob's questions you would try to help him by creating triggers for this broken model, as others did.

Comment: Sorry Wirus, wasn't trying to steal anyone's thunder. I wasn't even intending to feed a solution, just provide food for thought. To be honest, I'm still not clear on the OP's objectives, as I summed up in my last paragraph.

Comment: @rObjects, thanks that is what im trying to do, understand it and figure out the best way to do it :)

Comment: @rObjects i placed a new post with more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198930/mysql-help-and-guidance-with-db-normalising-relationships-and-foreign-keys) and a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2) to better explain what I'm trying to do.