# In a trigger how to insert values into another table but check if values already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Based on my previous post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18166576/2666688) im able to insert the values to the 2nd table when the status on first table changes, but it keeps adding indiscriminately, i need to check if the submit_id has already been inserted into the 2nd table and then update the fields not insert it gain, how would i do that check before the trigger is executed? 
Because the new.status and old.status refer to the row being edited not the row on table it's being inserted into, how can i compare that and insert or update if it already exists,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax for that

If order for it to work properly you have to have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `submitId` column in your second table (let's call it `students`).

```sql
ALTER TABLE students ADD UNIQUE (submitId);
```

Now an improved version of a trigger

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_au_submissions
AFTER UPDATE ON submissions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.status = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO students (submitId, studentName, submitDate, contacts, email) 
    VALUES (NEW.submitId, NEW.studentName, NEW.submitDate, NEW.contacts, NEW.email)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
      studentName = VALUES(studentName),
      submitDate = VALUES(submitDate),
      contacts = VALUES(contacts),
      email = VALUES(email);
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fc9b/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks @peterm, that was the missing step, i did not add the unique constrain, it's working as expected now.

Comment: i have one more question, now looking at what am trying to do and the way im going about it, am i going about it the right way and applying normalisation properly?
it's my first steps at mysql, so i wanna be sure im getting things right :)
Thanks

Comment: @BobMachine Unfortunately there isn't enough information in your original question to answer your this follow up question intelligently. I'd suggest to post another question putting together all your table schema and providing clear explanation what goal you're trying to achieve, what are the requirements.

Comment: i placed a new post with more detail [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198930/mysql-help-and-guidance-with-db-normalising-relationships-and-foreign-keys)here and a fiddle[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2) to better explain what I'm trying to do.
Thanks for the help so far :)