# MySQL best approach for db normalising, relationships and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database, database-normalization

There is an username/password verification step first then the database has following structure

```
^ is primary key

* uses foreign key


1.StudentDetails table
===========================================================================  
 ID^| Username   | Password | Email       | Address * | Website |Comments
====+============+==========+=============+===========+=========+========== 
1   | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxx  | xx@xxx.xxx  | 1         | http:// | text

2.Submissions table
===========================================================================================
ID^|Username*|SubmitDate|SelectedCourse*|Price*|Promotion*|SubmitComments|SubmitStatus*
===+=========+==========+===============+======+==========+==============+=================
1  |xxxxxxxxx|2013-7-12 |  int          | int  |  int     | text         | int


3.SubmitComplete table
==================================================
ID^| Username * | SelectionDate | SubmitStatus *  
====+============+===============+================
1   | xxxxxxxxxx |  2013-08-01   | int
```

Now I'm having an issue entering the address, when i try to enter the student details it won't accept until there is an address field, how best to tackle that?
When i do an left join selecting certain fields from StudentDetails and certain fields from Addresses, addresses don't show.

Im a mysql noob, so i'd like some guidance to see if the normalising and structure has been done correctly, or could it be done better, here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2) i couldn't get it to work properly, kept getting errors on the lines where i added the foreign keys, even though the building of the schema worked well on my machine.

The fiddle console says error on line 2 but it looks to me it's actually on line 76.
If there's anything i was unclear on, pls let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of the user **name**, I'd use the user **id** as a foreign key in the submissions and submitcomplete tables. (and add an unique constraint on student.username)

Comment: @wildplasser im not sure i understand u correctly, but if i do, that is what i did, u can see it in the fiddle Submissions.Username and SubmitComplete.Username both use StudentDetails.id as the key, what i had not done is the unique constrain.

Comment: Hi Bob, I've prepared new fiddle for you. I didn't fill tables with values, just created them, but at the bottom you can see my comments to your fiddle. You may find the fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c03dd

Comment: @Wirus Thanks for ur helpful comments (as usual) i think prob with my fiddle was not having index the keys first (noob mistake...lol Ooops)
As to ur comments, address 1, 2 3 is not different addresses, it add fields for longer addresses, different countries have different address structures. Submission fee, price, courses and promo are 4 dif entities, fee is paid once a year regardless of how many courses, new courses can be added and within it prices may change from year to year, Promo discount only affects course price not submission fee, that's why i did it like that, does it make sense?

Comment: Hi Bob, you must think of which properties belong to which object. Course has price. In your old structure, you would have many records for one course, but for different years. So you could just add price column to course table. Or you could create CourseDetails table with startDate, endDate, price, and store in Course only some common fields, like courseName, courseDesc etc. On the other hand, there may be few Promos for Course and user may choose one. So imho it should be property of submission. But it's just a quick comment because I didn't even have enough time to think your answer through

Comment: Promo has start and end dates. One student may submit while promo is active, but the second one may submit when the other promo is active. So,it's rather submission's property. You could then calculate price that student should pay basing on course's price and submissions promotion discount. But as I wrote... you must think this through, I'm affraid I will not be able to help you in a next days.

Comment: @Wirus thanks, u have been pointing out relevant things and good ideas, I'm still thinking of the details, this was my first run with it, i will fine tune at as i go.
I hope u enjoy ur leave and get a chance to go somewhere nice for a few days :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok let me explain you how it would be. I made an example with two tables that you can see below.

[image: simple model]

Then you can create your query.

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| addresses      |
| students       |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from students;
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | name     | last_name |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | jhon     | smith     |
|  2 | anderson | neo       |
|  3 | trinity  | jackson   |
+----+----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from addresses;
+----+-----------------+---------+
| id | address         | student |
+----+-----------------+---------+
|  1 | Av 1 2nd Street |       1 |
|  2 | Av 3 4 Street   |       2 |
|  3 | St 23 7 Av      |       3 |
+----+-----------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select s.name,s.last_name,a.address from students s join addresses a on a.student=s.id;
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| name     | last_name | address         |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| jhon     | smith     | Av 1 2nd Street |
| anderson | neo       | Av 3 4 Street   |
| trinity  | jackson   | St 23 7 Av      |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank you for your diligence, i eventually got to a similar solution
`SELECT 
sd.Username,
sd.Email,
sd.Website,
ad.Address_1,
ad.City,
ad.Country
      FROM StudentDetails sd, Addresses ad
      WHERE sd.id = ad.id`
The difference is ur address table only has 1 columns, mine has 3 that was part of the issue.
Now i was trying to concatenate my addresses columns (Address_1, Address_2, Address_3) if it was not NULL, but whenever i do that, i get null
query here
`CONCAT (ad.Address_1, ad.Address_2, ad.Address_3) AS fullAddress,`

Comment: In that case you should try conditions like CONCAT(IF(addr1,''),IF(addr2,''),IF(addr1,'')) AS full_address;

Comment: with IF like that it's giving me an error i tried IFNULL which does not give me error, but does not give me he desired result, i wanted to add a line break if it was not null after addr1 and addr2 so it's easier to read

Comment: i did not know this before but in mysql `IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)` IF function accepts three arguments and the result is returned based on if expr1 is TRUE.
If expr1 is evaluated to TRUE, the function returns expr2. Otherwise, expr3 is returned.
So that solved that bit :)

Comment: Hi Bob, it's me again:) IMHO keeping entire address in one field is not a good idea. You should have Addresses(id, studentId, Country, Region, City, address, number), where address is i.e. street. In such way you may validate those fields, search by them etc. Then you don't need this concats, ifs etc., you just join student with addresses and get one. You may add order column (or just assume that you get first one from join), you may add isDefault flag so that you may pre-fill some forms with addresses iwth default one.

Comment: @Wirus Address is not in 1 field, it's in a different table with all fields separated using FK to connect them.
I know ur getting ready for ur leave, but if u got a moment, help me fix my fiddle, that way it will be easier to visualise, the prob on fiddle seems to be when i insert FK when i remove them it works fine, but obviously it doesn't work as desired.
Could u elaborate on ur isDefault flag idea?
U know me, always ready to pick ur brain :)
Thanks

Comment: Hi Bob Machine please try again with this condition in your select "I had a mistake in the condition that i mentioned before". CONCAT(IF(addr1,addr1,''),"",IF(addr2,addr2,''),"",IF(addr3,addr3,'')) AS full_address;

Comment: @Bob, I know u don't have address in 1 field, I didn't mean your model, but the one proposed in fagace's answer. Could you prepare new fiddle? The one in your answer is empty. The purpose of isDefault (or whatever you name it) could be, that student may have few addresses for some reason (unless u don't allow him to have few?), but may want to mark one to have mails sent on this address, or whatever. Then, university worker, in case he wants to send some kind of mail, does not have to choose among addresses, because student has marked one to be used for communication.

Comment: @Wirus I've redone [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3140)  problem lines start @line 80
`ALTER TABLE `StudentDetails`
KEY `FK_address` (`Address`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_address` FOREIGN KEY (`Address`) REFERENCES `Addresses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `Submissions`
KEY `FK_username` (`Username`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_username` FOREIGN KEY (`Username`) REFERENCES `StudentDetails` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

Not enough space to put all lines here, but im adding FKs like this

Comment: @Wirus hey have u been able to see the fiddle now?

Comment: Yes, I've added comment underneath your question.

Answer (score 0):

option 1:
enter the adress data first, and use that id when createing the row in StudentDetails

option 2:
change the field StudentDetails.Address so its allow NULL valus, enter the StudentDetails, then the adress, and then update the StudentDetails.Address

Comment: thanks for suggestion, would i be able to do that from php?
Would you say the normalisation is correctly done?
Also could u take a look at my fiddle, to see what i may have done wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use foreign keys in number format So the Username should be the id of the StudentDetails table.

Can you put the SQL Query that you had tried to run?

Comment: thats what i did, u can take a look at the fiddle
here is the query
select *
from StudentDetails left join
     Addresses
     
     on StudentDetails.id = Addresses.id;
But the minute u specify certain fields form either side, only one side shows or i get an error

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. Addresses is another table isn't it?. If the model is correct but, why you are trying to join the id of both tables? If I were you, I would make the query like this:

SELECT  * FROM StudentDetails LEFT JOIN Addresses on StudentDetails.id = Addresses.student_id;

Wher student_id is the foreign key.

Comment: what im trying to do is select Username, Email and Website from StudentDetails table and Address_1, city and country from Addresses table.
How would the query be?